# R kruskal test with ddply

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data frame with 3 factor levels and 2 response variables .
I would like to see if  for each f1 'condition' the number of 'pheno' is significantly different for each f2 'plate'.

```
> str(qval_smhub_mltP)
'data.frame':   1401045 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ gene     : Factor w/ 10695 levels "P10-Lib-othLoc-PA0003-recF-NA-7881-b3700-eco.recF",..: 3361     4513 3219 3089 3988 4519 4414 4132 3072 4432 ...
 $ condition: Factor w/ 131 levels "A22.0.5","A22.1",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ qval     : num  0.601 0.731 0.383 0.68 0.143 ...
 $ plate    : Factor w/ 7 levels "P10","P11","P5",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
$ pheno    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I have tried the following ddply solution.

```
        CondPlate_PhenoPval<-ddply(qval_smhub_mltP,"condition",
    function(x) {
        k<-kruskal.test(pheno~plate,data=qval_smhub_mltP)
       # if (k$p.value < 0.05){
       #     ggplot(x,aes
       #     ggsave(file = paste(out_dir(paste(set,org,x$condition,"boxplotPhenoPerPlate.pdf",sep="."),sep="")))
       # }
    with(k,data.frame(statistic,p.value))
    }
)
```

However, I think the output is wrong because I get the same answer for each condition.
Any ideas on what I"m doing wrong.
ex.

```
119               STREPTOMYCIN.4  440.3202 5.943961e-92
120        SULFAMONOMETHOXINE.50  440.3202 5.943961e-92
121                     TEMP.30D  440.3202 5.943961e-92
122                     TEMP.42D  440.3202 5.943961e-92
123             TIGECYCLINE.0.25  440.3202 5.943961e-92
124              TIGECYCLINE.1.6  440.3202 5.943961e-92
125              TOBRAMYCIN.0.01  440.3202 5.943961e-92
126             TOBRAMYCIN.0.025  440.3202 5.943961e-92
127              TOBRAMYCIN.0.05  440.3202 5.943961e-92
128               TOBRAMYCIN.0.1  440.3202 5.943961e-92
129                VERAPAMIL.500  440.3202 5.943961e-92
130                YEPD.CANDIDAC  440.3202 5.943961e-92
```

Also, if I want to save boxplots for each condition that there is a significant difference for, is the above commented section in the right direction?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You are getting the same value each time because you are doing exactly the same thing each time. I suppose you want to use `x` somewhere in the function, maybe you meant to write  `k<-kruskal.test(pheno~plate,data=x)` ?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for spotting the mistake